# undefined symbol: Py_Initialize in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: python, c, apache2

I created my own apache module in C API with Python.

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "ap_config.h"
#include "python2.7/Python.h"
static char* a(){
Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
return "aba\t";
}
/* The sample content handler */
static int mor_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    if (strcmp(r->handler, "mor")) {
        return DECLINED;
    }
    r->content_type = "text/html";      

    if (!r->header_only)
     {  char *d;
     d=  a();
ap_rputs(d, r);
        ap_rputs("The sample page from mod_mor.c\n", r);}
    return OK;
}

static void mor_register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    ap_hook_handler(mor_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}

/* Dispatch list for API hooks */
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA mor_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF, 
    NULL,                  /* create per-dir    config structures */
    NULL,                  /* merge  per-dir    config structures */
    NULL,                  /* create per-server config structures */
    NULL,                  /* merge  per-server config structures */
    NULL,                  /* table of config file commands       */
    mor_register_hooks  /* register hooks                      */
};
```

But following error occurred. I don't understand it.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart 
apache2: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mor.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mor.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mor.so: `undefined symbol: Py_Initialize`
`Action 'configtest' failed`.
The Apache error log may have more information.
       ...fail!
```

Comment: Could you run `ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mor.so` and post the output?

Comment: How do you compile this module? How are you  adding a reference to libpython.so to your module? Are you compiling statically?

Comment: 1 .apxs2 -cia mod_mor.c 2. I can't add any reference to libpython.so.

Comment: **ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mor.so linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x002b2000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00b6d000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00ae0000)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a reference to libpython:

```
$ apxs2 -cia mod_mor.c -lpython2.7
```

Then you should be able to load your module.If you can not refer to the dynamic .so of python, then you could try using the .a version of the library:

```
$ apxs2 -cia mod_mor.c -Wl,-static -lpython2.7
```

However,you can get some complains if objects in libpython2.7.a  are not compiled with the -fPIC option; I haven't tried.

Comment: You are welcome. I note that this is probably your first question, so you could "accept" this answer if it was helpful to you ;-)

Comment: how i use .a version library? Apache restart is OK but don't show anything. I used **LoadModule intel_module       /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_intel.so
<Location /intel>
    SetHandler intel
    </Location>** and **http://localhost/intel**

Comment: It shouldn't show anything, unless there be an error or you explicitly ask for something to be printed from inside your module, on start-up(you could try that).

Comment: `mod_r4.lo -Wl,-static -lpython2.7
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s` error occuring.